# when click on next button or previous button at the same time active next li or provious li element by using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when I click on the next or previous buttons the list items need to active at the same time. if I click on next button the next list item needs to active (means color or background color) by using Javascript or typescript in angualr6.
thanks in advance.

- item 1
- item 2
- ***item 3***
- item 4

Previous    Next

```js
var list=document.getElementById("list").childElementCount;
var count = 0;

function activeclass(index){
   parent = document.getElementById("list");
   count += index;
   chailditem = parent.children[count];
   chailditem.style.color = 'red';
   if(count == list){
    count == 0
   }
}
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="item active">item 1<li>
  <li class="item">item 2<li>
  <li class="item">item 3<li>
  <li class="item">item 4<li>
<ul>


<button class="btn btn-default button-next" on-click="activeclass(-1)" type="button">Next</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button-prev" on-click="activeclass(1)" type="button">Previous</button>
```

Comment: Where's your HTML? or your attempt to write any code yourself? It's been 2 years since you posted any code at all - you've been spoiled with answers

Comment: that would be better off *in the question* where it is readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all it's not the decent solution, however you get an idea from here.**

```js
var count = 0;

function activeclass(val){
   var totalElem=document.getElementsByClassName("item");
   if(count > totalElem.length || count < 0) return;
  
   var list=document.getElementsByClassName("active");
   let elem;
   if(val == 'next') {
    elem = list[0].nextElementSibling;
    count++;
   }
   else {
    elem = list[0].previousElementSibling;
    count--;
   }
   
   list[0].classList.remove("active");
   elem.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="item active">item 1</li>
  <li class="item">item 2</li>
  <li class="item">item 3</li>
  <li class="item">item 4</li>
<ul>


<button class="btn btn-default button-next" onclick="activeclass('next')" type="button">Next</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button-prev" onclick="activeclass('prev')" type="button">Previo
```

**Please don't hesitate to let me know if you have any query.**